# How can I add options to the ckeditor5 toolbar? Such as Justification and other standard options

Tags: ckeditor5

[image]

Using Drupal 9 and Civi 5.63.3.  Options for justifying text are missing.  Various documentation and answers mention a ckeditor config options but not showing

Comment: Not a direct answer but consider https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/summernote as an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

you can config as below

Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences

In the page you should see Wysiwing Editor - Select CKEditor - which will give you the option to config

**Ref: Please click the link below - this is from demo site
https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/ckeditor?reset=1**

Please find the screenshot attached

I hope this helps !!!

[image]

Comment: The question was about ckeditor5, which does not have this.